# Uploading files via SAP Gateway via SAPUI5 (function import vs create_stream method)

Tags: abap

I was wondering what the best practice is regarding the uploading of files via the gateway.

There is a possibility to pass parameters via a function import. One could pass the **name** and **binary content** to a function import in the gateway and upload it that way.

Another possibility is to upload it via the `CREATE_STREAM` method found in the `DPC_EXT` class.

What is the cleanest way to do this? They both seem to be working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create stream. It's the more HTTP, REST, and OData-compliant way.

Function imports are not compliant to these standards, and should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

Function import is a way to do operations that does not match CRUDQ operations. For example accepting a document or confirming sale, You could of course use a Create method or an update but if You alreday using them for something HTTP PUT and GET can be used for function import.
It however should NOT be used if the operation matches Create Read Update Delete or Query.

EDIT:
Create (Read) Stream is a great (and recommended) way of sending files and it also uses GET and PUT so use this if You're just sending files (even with parameters).

Cheers.